# Apt not using proxy settings set in environment

Tags: debian, proxy, apt-get, apt

I have the following system wide settings in my /etc/profile

```
MY_PROXY_URL=http://192.168.128.251:3128
HTTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
HTTPS_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
FTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
http_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
https_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
ftp_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
export HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy
```

Other programs such as my web browser have no problems using the proxy settings. However, running any apt operation that requires internet connection fails due to failing to initiate a connection. Setting the proxy settings to the specific apt setting file /etc/apt/apt.conf solves this problem. Is there anyway to have apt use the proxy settings set in the environment?

Comment: You are right, I thought /etc/profile would be loaded if I changed user using the su command. Apparently it is only invoked for log in shells. If you copy your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments between myself and OP: `apt-get` and such is usually run under root. Maybe check root's environment with something like `sudo sh -c 'echo $http_proxy'`.

tl;dr: `/etc/profile` isn't loaded when `sudo`ing.

Comment: Omg. Thank you. After an entire afternoon of "Why is http_proxy set but apt not using the proxy".